# WPF Usercontrol with textboxes

Tags: wpf, textbox, user-controls

I have a WPF user control with a number of textboxes, this is hosted on a WPF window.
The textboxes are not currently bound but I cannot type into any of them.

I have put a breakpoint in the KeyDown event of one of the textboxes and it hits it fine and I can see the key I pressed.

The textboxes are declared as

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="4"
          x:Name="PostcodeSearch"
          Style="{StaticResource SearchTextBox}"
          KeyDown="PostcodeSearch_KeyDown"/>
```

The style is implemented as

```
<Style x:Key="SearchTextBox"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="140"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
```

I am hoping I have overlooked something obvious.

EDIT: I only added the KeyDown and KeyUp events just to prove that the keys presses were getting through. I do not have any custom functionality.

Comment: What else happens in the method "PostcodeSearch_KeyDown"?

Just using your pure XAML text box and style it all works fine for me, so the only thing left is that something in that method is affecting the box.

Comment: Also, is there anything set on or within the UserControl that could be effecting the TextBoxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PostcodeSearch_KeyDown-method (or anybody else before the textbox in the event-chain, could also be some parent-control in the Preview_KeyDown-Event) sets `e.Handled = true` (e being the eventArgs), the event will not be propagated to further consumers (as the textbox) and thus no action will occur.

Another reason might be that your WPF-Window is hosted in a WinForms-Application, then you will need to call

```
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(YourWindow);
```

To make keyboard interaction work (google/bing for WPF WinForms InterOp for a full explanation)